# Mount and add 2 Disk on our Server with already 2 Disk with RAID 1

Tags: server, centos6, mount, disk

We have a server (centos 6) and our disk is nearly full, we asked for 2 new disk to be added on our server but don't know how to proceed to mount and see it on our server.

Thanks

Comment: we use already RAID 1 with 2 current disks

Answer (score 0):

If you are using RAID1 with the LVM partition then you can increase your current partition otherwise you will have to create new home partition on your server with the new disk and mount it. Once new disk is mounted you can move our current data from old disk to new disk.